# Is Gallup's Clifton StrengthsFinder able to identify the strengths of an individual?

Tags: cognitive-science

On [their website](https://www.gallupstrengthscenter.com/Home/en-US/Index) Gallup claim that their Clifton StrengthsFinder test is able to accurately identify personal strengths. I am skeptical of this method because the test itself simply asks people how they view themselves.

I'm curious what science, if any, there is to support the claims that Gallup is making.

Gallup has been careful to not make very specific claims about their test on their website, which seems suspicious to me. They make a few claims about the utility of knowing the information the test is meant to provide, but no specific claims about the test being able to provide that information. However, there are some more specific claims in [this technical report](http://strengths.gallup.com/private/Resources/CSFTechnicalReport031005.pdf).